# AutoComplete Material UI onNewRequest wrong behavior

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, react-redux, material-ui

I am working in a little app with react-redux and material-ui and I am having problems with the autocomplete field when I use onNewRequest property. It is fired like onClick to the component and not when I select one of the elements in the list.

The code:

```
const test = () => {
  alert("Something");
}
```

And the component works with a service response to show the data

```
case Status.OK:
  return <AutoComplete
    floatingLabelText="Origin"
    filter={(searchText, key) => (searchText.length >= 3 && key.indexOf(searchText) !== -1)}
    dataSource={ renderOrigins(response.data) }
    openOnFocus={false}
    maxSearchResults={3}
    onNewRequest={ test() }
    onClick={onClick(dispatch)}
    style={{marginRight: '30px'}}
  />
```

It's basically that, but when I select the autocomplete field the function test() is fired, and when I select a element on the list nothing happen.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, onNewRequest={ test() } should be onNewRequest={ test }